# Issue with flow in exporting the PowerApps application

Tags: export, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

I have developed a PowerApps application in my personal environment. I am trying to move that application to QA environment. The application is containing a single Microsoft flow which was created by me. When I am trying to export the application, I am getting the below issue. 'The caller object id is 'd3472859-124e-4042-bab6-074734ee7d59'. Connection '44b77fad-3465-4ad1-a705-b1192793e932' to 'shared_logicflows' cannot be used to activate this flow, either because this is not a valid connection or because it is not a connection you have access permission for. Either replace the connection with a valid connection you can access or have the connection owner activate the flow, so the connection is shared with you in the context of this flow.' I checked all the possible access. I am the owner of both Microsoft flow and PowerApps application. Can you please help me in understanding and fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance.